# How does Mist know that I'm using Ethereum Classic?

Tags: ether, mist, ethereum-classic

I went to the guide on Ethereum Classic website, and the instructions there are exactly the same as with installing a regular Ethereum account. 
There is no difference, so it looks like I can send both ETH and ETC to the same address in Mist wallet, how will Mist be able to separate them? I don't see any option there

Answer (score 1):

The client software is slightly different.

Addresses are the same on both chains because it's the effectively the same open source software that creates the addresses. When the hard fork happened and ETC classic continued on the original chain all those running the new version of the software (the hard forked version) had the same balance on both chains using the same address.

The config for the main chain is as follows (in [config.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/feeccdf4ec1084b38dac112ff4f86809efd7c0e5/params/config.go#L28) ):

```
MainnetChainConfig = &ChainConfig{
ChainId:        MainNetChainID,
HomesteadBlock: MainNetHomesteadBlock,
DAOForkBlock:   MainNetDAOForkBlock,
DAOForkSupport: true,
EIP150Block:    MainNetHomesteadGasRepriceBlock,
EIP150Hash:     MainNetHomesteadGasRepriceHash,
EIP155Block:    MainNetSpuriousDragon,
EIP158Block:    MainNetSpuriousDragon,
Ethash:         new(EthashConfig),
```

it is these parameters I believe and someone is welcome to correct me, the DAOForkSupport true tells the software this client is supporting the forked version not the original ETC classic version and to act differently, in simple terms.  Maybe worth comparing the two files from the two repositories and see the different.

Comment: But in Ethereum Classic in the guide the link is:
https://ethereum-classic-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account-management.html#using-mist-ethereum-wallet

and you can see it links to the regular Mist, with no changes?

Comment: Are you sure they are not linking to an old version of Mist release prior to the hardfork.  What wallet version do they link to.

Comment: Ethereum Wallet and Mist 0.9.3 "Cliente Ligero"

Comment: This was the version of Mist before the hard fork thus works on ETC, later versions have that parameter above set above indicating to use the newer ETH chain.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's before the hard fork, what happens if I try to send both ETH and ETC to the address?

Comment: Having looked at the etc website and the link to Mist.  Your correct in that they do link to the latest version I was wrong above.  Mist is not the blockchain, its the geth node that the Mist wallet connects to determines which chain your on. The Mist wallet is a nice user friendly UI interfacing with geth.  I have been reading their documentation and it does not say anywhere about how to get onto the ETC chain.  It looks like anyone that follows their guide will be on ETH.

Answer (score 0):

You can download mist for ethereum classic from here: https://github.com/ethereumproject/mist/releases